# Deleting data from inside of cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to delete the data in a cell from the detailedViewController. I am trying to delete both an image and a video from the cell. For the video, I am saving both the url and the video data to core data, but I am only saving the url to the cell. Is there a way to delete a video based on a url (like deleteDataWithURL)? Here is the code I am using:

```
- (void) deleteVideAndImage {

    NSManagedObject *objectToBeDeleted = [self managedObject]; // Replace this with whatever you use to reference the managed object
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [objectToBeDeleted managedObjectContext];
    [context deleteObject:objectToBeDeleted];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: You're responsible to maintain the "data source" -- simply modifying the table view is not sufficient.  In fact, worst case you can *only* modify the data source and then do a `reloadData` on the table view to cause it to rebuild the visible table from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

That is not going to do anything to your table view.  Deleting from Core Data will delete it from your **Model** but it will not change your **View** unless you have the two connected.  If you want something removed from a **View** you should look at the **Controller** not the **Model**.

Comment: So the image is disappearing from the tableView, it's just that the video isn't being deleted

Comment: Same answer, your question does not make sense.  I would suggest reviewing the documentation on MVC and Table Views.